# FancyBox 1.3.1 closes after 1 second without any action

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have inherited the following:

```
      <!-- start popup-->

 <script>
jQuery.ajax( {
  url: '//freegeoip.net/json/',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(location) {
    // If the visitor is browsing from Canada.
    if (location.country_code === 'CA') {
      // Tell him about the Canadian store.
      jQuery.fancybox.open(jQuery('#message23'),{ helpers: { overlay: {closeClick: false}}});
    }
  }
} );

</script>

<div style="display:none;">
  <div id="message23" style="padding:30px;">
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
    <p>Looks like you are in Canada. Please use our Canadian website<br /><a href="https://www.logbooks.ca"><img src="{{ 'canada-flag.png' | asset_url }}" alt="Canada Flag"><br />www.logbooks.ca</a></p>
  </div>
</div>


<!--end popup -->
```

it is on logbooks.com (site will generate a popup if you are on the .com part while browsing from Canada). What keeps happening is that as soon as the page fully turns on the popup disappears and removes the up and down slider from the page.

I have limited understanding of jquery and javascript and since I didn't implement this I am especially not sure why it does it.

if you need more info let me know.

Comment: Do you have any other scripts on the page, besides jQuery and FancyBox?

Comment: there are is some javascript too. I am not sure i understand your question; do you mean script types or just instances? As in, more than just that particular jQuery script? As in, if i have other jQuery scripts on my page or other scripts that are not jQuery? This is shopify so the whole thing is made in liquid; and there is a javascript that gets the CSS for different sizes. However, the page is www.logbooks.com if i am misunderstanding your question you can see the scripts there too. Thanks in advance!

Comment: look for a `setTimeout` function in your code